# Can I get all flags, switches and samples in django waffle in one call?

Tags: django

I need to get all configured properties in the user context. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of getting all of them at once, the documentation of waffle didn't seem to mention any such facility.

The other option of course is to just query the tables myself.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a quick look at the source code

https://github.com/django-waffle/django-waffle/blob/master/waffle/views.py#L19

here it takes all flags and their status

```
from waffle import get_waffle_flag_model
flags = get_waffle_flag_model().get_all()
flag_values = [(f.name, f.is_active(request)) for f in flags]
```

hope this helps

Comment: is_active does a database query per flag (for group based flags). So you should avoid looping like this on hot code paths especially if you have a lot of flags